# Using Geolocation in PHP

Tags: php, api, geolocation

I have a PHP page containing the following code to get latitude and longitude from a user input postal code.

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the
>   server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in
>   /home/metsrobo/public_html/PHPPage2.php on line 4
>
> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=750341&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDa3Jhr3c5x_2GWrPwRoMWDXrMSYl3KvOA):
>   failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in line 4.

```
<?php
    function getLnt($zip){
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($zip)."&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDa3Jhr3c5x_2GWrPwRoMWDXrMSYl3KvOA";
    $result_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
    return $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
         $val = getLnt('750341');
         echo "Latitude: ".$val['lat']."<br>";
         echo "Longitude: ".$val['lng']."<br>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you restricted the API key to be accessible by domain basis or ip or something else, i tried clicking the link, access was denied.

Comment: May i know what are the settings I should put when creating the api?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8venng

I put the settings like this, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use api key with url, remove api key then it will work, because to get latitude and longitude you don't need api key. Change url like below

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=750341&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `file_get_contents()` function to work, firstly you need to enable the `allow_url_fopen` and set its value to On.

Regarding the same, you can try two things.

1. Create an `.htaccess` file and keep it in root folder ( sometimes it may need to place it one step back folder of the root) and paste this code there.

   ```
   php_value allow_url_fopen On
   ```
2. Create a `php.ini` file (for update server `php5.ini`) and keep it in root folder (sometimes it may need to place it one step back folder of the root) and paste the following code there:

   ```
   allow_url_fopen = On;
   ```

Hope it helps you.